# Visual software tool for creating complex branching logic

Tags: eclipse, ide, visual-programming

Is there a visual software tool (no batch coding/programming language) which can enable an end user to create complex branching logic like this tool : http://www.visuallogic.org/VLTutorial.html . Any eclipse plgun-in similar to this. I want that complex logic expressed by the end user to be represented in XML form

Answer (score 1):

A set of plug-ins called vIDE might help you - it's a tool based on GMF I am currently developing. You can check out the project [here](https://launchpad.net/vide).

It's still far from stable or finished, but you can draw flowcharts in it which get dynamically converted to Ecore models (which in term can be exported to XML).

[image]

My current effort is to support generation of executable Python code from the drawn flowchart.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [UniMod](http://unimod.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

In term of pure flowchart diagrams (and not UML diagrams), I didn't find anything recent.

- [flowchartstudio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flowchartstudio/) is not supported on recent Eclipse version

[image]

- [flowchart4j](http://flowchart4j.codeswat.com/) (not free) is interesting (for Java programs, so no XML representation)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

DRAKON Editor
http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/
It it supports visual programming in several programming languages, including Java, Processing.org, D, C#, C/C++ (with Qt support), Python, Tcl, Javascript, Lua and Erlang.
Why to use DRAKON than other diagramming systems?

- No line intersections. You will never find in DRAKON diagram two or
  more lines intersecting each other! Not seen in other diagramming
  systems!
- Silhouette structure. It allows to break one diagram in to several
  logical parts. Not seen in other diagramming systems!
- No slanting or curved lines. Only straight lines with right angles.
- Icons are placed only on vertical lines.
- Branching is done in a simple, visible and consistent way.
- Each diagram has one entry and one exit.

More about DRAKON here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRAKON

Answer (score 0):

Take a lool at [TUM.CMS.VplControl](https://github.com/tumcms/TUM.CMS.VPLControl)

[image]